# How to create UITableViewCell in category wise arrange JSON objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, uitableview

[I want to like this, Please have a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mosr1.jpg)

I have UITableViewCell and I create category wise arrange JSON data. I fetched all our value but how to arrange category inside particular array, like this first category "Automotive" in side "business_details" under two different-different array. I want to arrange category in UITableViewCell. how it possible, please help. Thank You

## JSON

```
{
    "status": [
    {
      "business_category_name": "Automotive",
      "business_details": [
        {
          "img_url": "http:\/\/edutimeapp.com\/toshow\/chamber-of-commerc\/member-logo\/1467813900-263.jpg",
          "name": "ssmpl",
          "des": "SIXTH SENSE MARKETING PVT LTD",
          "address": "m2",
          "email": "hr@sixthsenseit.com",
          "phone": "09999999999",
          "member_since": "2016-07-06",
          "img_company": "http:\/\/edutimeapp.com\/toshow\/chamber-of-commerc\/member-logo\/1467813900-263.jpg",
          "website": "www.sixthsenseit.com",
          "city": "indore",
          "state": "mp",
          "zip": "452001"
        },
        {
          "img_url": "http:\/\/edutimeapp.com\/toshow\/chamber-of-commerc\/member-logo\/1467814186-DSC_5854.jpg11.jpg",
          "name": "h",
          "des": "",
          "address": "gkjg",
          "email": "jgjg",
          "phone": "gjg",
          "member_since": "2016-07-06",
          "img_company": "http:\/\/edutimeapp.com\/toshow\/chamber-of-commerc\/member-logo\/1467814186-DSC_5854.jpg11.jpg",
          "website": "jg",
          "city": "jg",
          "state": "gjg",
          "zip": "jgj"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "business_category_name": "Banks\/Credit Unions\/Landers",
      "business_details": [
        {
          "img_url": "http:\/\/edutimeapp.com\/toshow\/chamber-of-commerc\/member-logo\/1464667619-pnc.jpg",
          "name": "PNC Bank",
          "des": "PNC offers a wide range of services for all our customers, from individuals and small businesses, to corporations and government entities",
          "address": "",
          "email": "andrea.kendall@pnc.com",
          "phone": "260-422-5922",
          "member_since": "2016-05-31",
          "img_company": "http:\/\/edutimeapp.com\/toshow\/chamber-of-commerc\/member-logo\/1464667619-pnc.jpg",
          "website": "",
          "city": "Fort Wayne",
          "state": "IN",
          "zip": "46808"
        }
      ]
    }
    ]
}
```

## My code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    names = [NSMutableArray new];
    ntm= [NSMutableArray new];
    adrsary=[NSMutableArray new];
    phoneary=[NSMutableArray new];
    emailary=[NSMutableArray new];
    websiteary=[NSMutableArray new];
    sensary=[NSMutableArray new];
    desary=[NSMutableArray new];
    image=[NSMutableArray new];

    [self.tabel_view setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];

    NSURLRequest *req=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://edutimeapp.com/toshow/chamber-of-commerc/ws/fetch_member.php"]];
    response =[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSError *error;

    NSLog(@"Error in receiving data %@",error);
    NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&error];
    NSLog(@"response data %@",json);

    NSArray *statuses = [json objectForKey:@"status"];

    for(NSDictionary *status in statuses){
        NSString *bussiness_category=[status valueForKey:@"business_category_name"];
        [names addObject:bussiness_category];
         NSLog(@"busness details %@",names);

        for(NSDictionary *details in [status objectForKey:@"business_details"])
        {
            NSString *name=[details valueForKey:@"name"];
            [ntm addObject:name];
            NSLog(@"name %@",ntm);


            NSString *address=[details valueForKey:@"address"];
            [adrsary addObject:address];
            NSLog(@"address %@",adrsary);

            NSString *phone=[details valueForKey:@"phone"];
            [phoneary addObject:phone];
            NSLog(@"phone %@",phoneary);

            NSString *email=[details valueForKey:@"email"];
            [emailary addObject:email];
            NSLog(@"email %@",emailary);

            NSString *website=[details valueForKey:@"website"];
            [websiteary addObject:website];
            NSLog(@"website %@",websiteary);

            NSString *memsens=[details valueForKey:@"member_since"];
            [sensary addObject:memsens];
            NSLog(@"mem. sense %@",sensary);

            NSString *des=[details valueForKey:@"des"];
            [desary addObject:des];
            NSLog(@"desc. %@",desary);

            NSString *img=[details valueForKey:@"img_url"];
            [image addObject:img];
            NSLog(@"image. %@",image);
        }
      }

for (int i=0; i<[names count]; i++) {
    [arrayForBool addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
}
    [self.tabel_view reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
 return names.count;
 }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if ([[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:section] boolValue]) {
    return emailary.count;
}
else
    return 0;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 70;

}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

UIView *sectionHeaderView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width,70)];

sectionHeaderView.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];

sectionHeaderView.tag=section;

UIView *sectionsubHeaderView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width,60)];

sectionsubHeaderView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];

UIImageView *arrow=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,60, 60)];

[arrow setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow"]];

UILabel *Lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 0,tableView.frame.size.width-60, 60)];

Lbl.text=[names objectAtIndex:section];

Lbl.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

[sectionsubHeaderView addSubview:arrow];

[sectionsubHeaderView addSubview:Lbl];

[sectionHeaderView addSubview:sectionsubHeaderView];

UITapGestureRecognizer  *headerTapped   = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionHeaderTapped:)];

[sectionHeaderView addGestureRecognizer:headerTapped];

return  sectionHeaderView;

 }

- (void)sectionHeaderTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
 {

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:gestureRecognizer.view.tag];
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    BOOL collapsed  = [[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue];
    for (int i=0; i<[names count]; i++) {
        if (indexPath.section==i) {
            [arrayForBool replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!collapsed]];
        }
    }
    [self.tabel_view reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:gestureRecognizer.view.tag] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

}


}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MemberTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ht"];
    if (cell==nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }


     cell.title.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[ntm objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.email.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[emailary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.address_lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[adrsary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.phone_lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[phoneary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.web_lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[websiteary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.sens_lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sensary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.des_lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[desary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [image objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
    cell.image_view.image =image;

    return  cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

[arrayForBool replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];

[self.tabel_view reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Comment: you can do this via making business_category as a section of tableview and return numberOfRows for each section is no. of object in business_details array.

Comment: It's possible but you are perfect your screen shot like that coding more and coding less that use tableview header. tableview header is height fixed.

Comment: @Dev.RK what can i do please help

Comment: I think you want expandable tableview ? means by clicking section header expand/collapse section.

Comment: @BhadreshKathiriya This screenshot of android application, I want implement  in i-phone app

Comment: @Dev.RK you are absolutely right.

Comment: @Dev.RK how it possible please help.

Comment: @A.Kumawat refer this- https://github.com/fuzz-productions/FZAccordionTableView

Comment: @A.Kumawat please check my below answer and let me know if you have any issue with answer.

Comment: @Dev.RK just minute wait, i will try. please wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this-

take a global array i.e. `NSMutableArray  *arrayForBool;` with your other array. Allocate this array in `viewDidLoad()` i.e. `arrayForBool=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`

Now add these lines of code in `connectionDidFinishLoading` just before 
`[tableview reloadData]`-

```
for (int i=0; i<[names count]; i++) {
        [arrayForBool addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    }
```

Here is complete code-

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MemberTableViewCell.h"
#import "secondVC.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{

    NSMutableData *response;
    NSMutableArray  *arrayForBool;
    NSMutableArray *business_details_array;
    NSMutableArray *names;
    NSDictionary *passDict;


}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    names = [NSMutableArray new];

    arrayForBool=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [self.tableView setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];

    NSURLRequest *req=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://edutimeapp.com/toshow/chamber-of-commerc/ws/fetch_member.php"]];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];

    if( connection )
    {

        response = [NSMutableData new];

    }


}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response1
{
    [response setLength:0];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [response appendData:data];
}


-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSError *error;

    NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&error];

    NSArray *statuses = [json objectForKey:@"status"];
    names=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[statuses valueForKey:@"business_category_name"]];
    business_details_array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[statuses valueForKey:@"business_details"]];



    for (int i=0; i<[names count]; i++) {
        [arrayForBool addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return names.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:section] boolValue]) {
        return [[business_details_array objectAtIndex:section] count];
    }
    else
        return 0;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 70;

}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    UIView *sectionHeaderView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width,70)];

    sectionHeaderView.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];

    sectionHeaderView.tag=section;

    UIView *sectionsubHeaderView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width,60)];

    sectionsubHeaderView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];

    UIImageView *arrow=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,60, 60)];

    [arrow setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];

    UILabel *Lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 0,tableView.frame.size.width-60, 60)];

    Lbl.text=[names objectAtIndex:section];

    Lbl.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

    [sectionsubHeaderView addSubview:arrow];

    [sectionsubHeaderView addSubview:Lbl];

    [sectionHeaderView addSubview:sectionsubHeaderView];

    UITapGestureRecognizer  *headerTapped   = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionHeaderTapped:)];

    [sectionHeaderView addGestureRecognizer:headerTapped];

    return  sectionHeaderView;

}

- (void)sectionHeaderTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:gestureRecognizer.view.tag];
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        BOOL collapsed  = [[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue];
        for (int i=0; i<[names count]; i++) {
            if (indexPath.section==i) {
                [arrayForBool replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!collapsed]];
            }
        }
        [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:gestureRecognizer.view.tag] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    }


}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MemberTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ht"];
    if (cell==nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }


    cell.title.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[business_details_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"name"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.email.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[business_details_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"email"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.address_lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[business_details_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"address"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.phone_lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[business_details_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"phone"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.web_lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[business_details_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"website"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.sens_lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[business_details_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"member_since"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.des_lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[business_details_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"des"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[business_details_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"img_url"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]];

    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

    cell.image_view.image =image;

    return  cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [arrayForBool replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];

    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    passDict=[[business_details_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gotoSeconVC" sender:self];
}
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"gotoSeconVC"]) {
        secondVC *vc=[segue destinationViewController];
        vc.myPreviousVCDict=passDict;
    }
}
@end
```

Now in `secondVC.h` file-

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface secondVC : UIViewController
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSDictionary *myPreviousVCDict;
@end
```

`NSLog()` this dictionaty in `viewDidLoad()`. Hope this will help you. Using this you can make custom header of Section and expandable section.

Here is the output screen-

[image]

storyBoard must Look like this-

[image]

and this is member_details what you want--

[image]

Comment: I used your code and run project show only header "business_category_name" then i click any one "business_category_name" and crash application and error show bellow :- -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 6 beyond bounds [0 .. 5]'

Comment: are you there, i am stuck please help.

Comment: successfully run but one category header in all category data show. Dev.RK all our working good, click on header and expand cell only can't divided category wise. please help me :(

Comment: Sorry for late reply but i told you please remove line cell.name.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; from cellforrowatindexpath method

Comment: I remove this line  cell.name.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; in my code

Comment: can you update your question with your latest code so that i can identify where is the issue or you can debug where error occurs. Code works fine..

Comment: now problem is all headers in all category show. cant divided particular array

Comment: i get all sector in one category

Comment: please add this line arrayForBool=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; in viewDidLoad(). you forgot to add this line.

Comment: same issue please ones saw image uploaded by me. i want same formate

Comment: this time all category inside all array category details show

Comment: check my output screen is like your image. Customize your cell as you want.. and use asynchronous  image downloading in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: bank/ credit unions/ landers in a only one details but your image in a all category details show

Comment: are you there?  Can I send you a link to the project

Comment: Ok wait please  i implement in my project

Comment: OMG! its working very very well. thank you thank you sooo much dear sir. really you are genius. thanks a lot :)

Comment: yes my problem is solved and please check i voted you answer .

Comment: same code select cell and pass data another view controller. I will try but any cell select and pass data only first cell data.

Comment: you can get dictionary object by adding this line in didSelectRow--  [[business_details_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]

Comment: didSelectRow-- [[business_details_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] i added this line after how to pass?

Comment: in segue method which object pass?

Comment: you have to make a global dictionary object and pass this object... as above link passing..

Comment: only create segue method and one example please

Comment: Have you done Segue Connection In StoryBoard? No, then first you create segue in storyBoard from oneVC to another VC.

Comment: Now take a global dictionary object then initialize this object in didSelectRow i.e.  yourDictObject=[[business_details_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: after this line call perparForSegue method i.e. [self prepareForSegue:@"yourSegueIdentifier" sender:self];

Comment: now please refer my link how i pass object to another VC.. In Link i use NSNumber but you have to use NSDictionary object..

Comment: error show bellow :- [__NSCFConstantString identifier]

Comment: what is your segue identifier in storyBoard..? paste your identifier in this lin-- [self prepareForSegue:@"changeThisWithYourSegueIdentifier" sender:self];

Comment: I follow your tricks but can't pass. how it possible Dev.RK sir

Comment: Please check complete updated answer... this will solve your problem. :)

Comment: click cell same data pass another view. so please check my project https://www.dropbox.com/s/8cank0akncuce27/Demo.zip?dl=0

Comment: download my project file and please solve my problem. please remember i want different-different value pass like name, image, address phone, website.

Comment: dear I'm passing dictionary, So you can get all data using valueForKey from dictionary..

Comment: please delete your segue from storyBoard cell selection.. and add this segue from memberVC to memberDetails.. No need to change anything in code.

Comment: Dear sir same dictionary pass any select cell

Comment: sorry I cant understand you last message

Comment: please sir have a look only one time dropbox.com/s/8cank0akncuce27/Demo.zip?dl=0

Comment: I have looked it dear.. have you tried what i'm saying for segue in storyBoard. and check your log what arayData you get..

Comment: check new screenshot.. I think you want this.. M I right?

Comment: Yes I want dictionary but i clicked cell and two times push member_details viewcontroller

Comment: I told you remove tableviewcell selection segue from storyBoard and make segue from as storyboard tells above..

Comment: your last message cant understand

Comment: I have done the changes in your code download and let me know.. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lxfzyyvkq709gs5/AACcryjHhRSn2kwYG7WFUZa5a?dl=0

Comment: Seriously sir you are very helping person. I have no words in my life. my english is bad otherwise i say many words. Thank you Dev.RK sir salute :)